# Being able to interrupt a chatbot in realtime

Tags: streaming, dialogflow-es, real-time, chatbot, alexa-skills-kit

My goal is to make a chatbot capable of reading a list of article titles (long list, could take 5 minutes for the chatbot to read orally the entire list) and the user can navigate in real-time on the answer saying: next, previous, share facebook, share twitter, read full article, go back to article list, etc. I think a rule based chatbot could make it, no NLP needed.

I started to develop my own conversation logic with Google Dialogflow. The chatbot reads the article list but it is not possible (orally !) to 'cut' the chatbot in the middle of the list to say: 'next', 'previous', etc... without having to at least repeat the name of the article or the article number which is not convenient for my needs at all.

For instance, the bot starts reading article titles: "article 1, Elon Musk reads books. article 2, self driving car industry hot. article 3, ... article n." When the bot reads "self driving car industry hot", the user says in the middle: "tell me more" (orally). And then the bot understands it was reading article 2 when it has been interrupted by the user so it goes to the article itself and read the full article.

Would be happy to hear about how to be able to build such kind of chatbot (only vocal is needed), in python would be appreciated. Ideally I would be able to put the bot as many places as possible (amazon alexa, google home, etc).

Comment: If you are doing this vocally, are you trying to use the Dialogflow telephony interface, or use Dialogflow with the Google Assistant?

Comment: I am using the Dialogflow Google assistant @Prisoner

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "without having to at least repeat the name of the article or the article number". Do you mean that it doesn't know when it was interrupted? Can you provide some conversational examples to illustrate what you're trying to do?

Comment: @Prisoner I made an edit to give an example. Yes I mean it does not know when it was interrupted. Thats the problem ! I managed to make a clickable list when the user speak on the chat (written) -> the list or article titles the bot reads is a clickable list. But when it is fully oral, it is impossible for the bot to know what article it was reading when the user says 'tell me more about this one'